# directive with ng-if not rendering in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-if

I'm trying to render a directive whenever I get the search results back. My plan was to keep a scope variable `algoliaSearch` initially `false` and whenever I get back search results I change it to `true`. Then in my view I tried to render the directive based on the value of my variable.

```js
  .directive('searchResults', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/search/directives/templates/searchResults.template.html',
      controller: ['$scope', 'AlgoliaSearchService', function ($scope, AlgoliaSearchService) {
        $scope.hits = [];
        $scope.nbHits = null;
        $scope.algoliaSearch = false;

        AlgoliaSearchService.on('result', results => {
          $scope.algoliaSearch = true;
          $scope.hits = results.hits;
          $scope.nbHits = results.nbHits;
          console.log($scope.algoliaSearch)
        });

      }]
    };
  })
```

In my view I want to render the directive when I get the search results back

```html
<search-results ng-if="algoliaSearch"></search-results>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't render anything on searching and even `console.log($scope.algoliaSearch)` doesn't print anything on console.
However if i use like

```html
<search-results></search-results>
```

or

```html
<search-results ng-if="true"></search-results>
```

Then it renders and the `console.log` works but that is not the way I want to.
My problem is why it doesn't conditionally render the directive based on my scope variable.
I want to make it render conditionally once I get back the search results.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive html `<search-results ng-if="algoliaSearch"></search-results>` is not showing because it's looking for a variable in $scope `algoliaSearch` before it even renders and executes the directive code. Not only is that variable not in $scope, but it's further not available until that ng-if is true.

To fix this, your best bet is either to change your ng-if to be something in $scope or, better yet, just have the `<search-results></search-results>` directive, and for the html in `...searchResults.template.html` to contain the boolean switch, something like

```
<div class='search-results' ng-if='algoliaSearch'>
  <div ng-repeat='....'>
    <!-- etc -->
```

Comment: thanks! didnt come across my mind i could use it inside the directive. new to ang1